# How do I boot into a basic graphics view?

Tags: session, command-line, gnome

How do I start a session that will give me he very basic graphics or even just terminal view?
I would like to start applications just by typing their name.

I would like to avoid the gui stuff as much as possible and use application only by need.

Is that possible at all?

Thanks,
Akis

Answer (score 1):

There are light-weight minimalistic window managers such as [xmonad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmonad), [ratpoison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratpoison), [awesome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_%28window_manager%29), [wmii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmii), [dwm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwm), [Ion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_%28window_manager%29), etc.
[Fluxbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxbox) and [Openbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbox) are heavier than the above mentioned but still very light.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> will bring you to a pure terminal environment. Depending on your configuration, F2 up to F6 will also do it. 
Note: You will not be able to run any programs that require a GUI in these modes.

To come back into the graphical environment, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. This is also implementation dependant.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can press the dash key (the windows key) and immediately begin to type the name of your application. This is to satisfy your petition *"to start applications just by typing their name"*. Also, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> allow you to do the same, but the intention is to write a command.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new desktop session file in /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Terminal
RequiredComponents=gnome-terminal
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=metacity
DefaultProvider-notifications=notify-osd
DesktopName=GNOME
```

In the login manager, change session to 'Terminal'. [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/gnome-session.1.html)

Create a new .desktop file in /usr/share/xsessions/

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=icanhazterminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Icon=
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

Note that you can pass `gnome-terminal` the --maximize or --full-screen parameters. You can also use `xterm` or `uxterm` or some other terminal emulator instead of gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When the computer is booting, hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button.
GRUB (the bootloader) will now appear.
Chose to boot into recovery mode.
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword